# What is the exoplayer2 equivalent for Hls.Events.FRAG_LOADED event present in hlsJs library

Tags: http-live-streaming, exoplayer2.x

We have used hlsJs library (ref: https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js) in Chrome browser to play HLS files.

There we have an event called Hls.Events.FRAG_LOADED which provides information about the hls fragment loaded like sequence number, start and end PTS and any custom tag attached to the fragment (ref: https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#FRAG_LOADED)

Is there an equivalent event or api which we can listen to in ExoPlayerv2 for Android which can provide me same information about the media segment loaded?

Why I need this?

In my streaming server I am putting some custom EXT tag for each media fragment & i want to read that data when a media fragment is loaded in my player.

This is what I get from hlsJs on chrome browser for FRAG_LOADED event.
Need similar data from exoplayer

[image]

Any pointer will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking into the AdaptiveMediaSourceEventListener onLoadComplete method and use the DataSpec object to get both URL and Format objects which can be used to extract some data like bitrate and position of the segments. I do not know if there is an equivalent API out there for what you are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately the DataSpec object doesnot have the custom tag or the media_sequence number that I was looking for :(